# Android net ethernet import

Tags: android, import, sdk, ethernet

I cant import android.net.ethernet because it doesnt seems in the list.The list contains android.net.wifi but there is no file about ethernet.How can i download the android.net.ethernet sdk?

I install all sdk from adt but the problem still continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe the platform contains ethernet package. You can find the source here [EthernetManager](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/frameworks_base/source/248edcc9f3ee2a69be568906af6ebad376817e47:ethernet/java/android/net/ethernet). Read here [No API documentation for android.net.ethernet](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34253)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `android.net.ethernet` package in the Android SDK. While there may be one in the OS proper, it is not part of the SDK, and therefore cannot be imported by an SDK app.

Comment: Yes there is i found java codes but i cant import them

Comment: @Shockelduck: That is because there is no `android.net.ethernet` package in the Android SDK.